# Issue using a public function class to get date/time into database

Tags: php, function, pdo

I am learning how to use a framework I found on youtube (I know probably not the best) and in general how to use public function from class files. The tutorial never really explained how to use it beyond logging in and what else can be done.

What I am currently doing is trying to add a last logged in date/time.

One of the classes is a user class. This file pretty much is used for updating the user info and the user database table.

There is a public function called `update`. I am attempting to use this function to add in the date when the user logs in. I am getting an error that I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: There was a problem updating! in
>   /classes/User.php:37 Stack trace: #0
>   /public_html/login.php(32): User->update('last_login',
>   '2019-08-16 07:0...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /classes/User.php on line 37

The user class update code line is the `throw new` in this bit of code:

```
if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
    throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
}
```

The login error is from the line where I am trying to use the update function:
    $loginTime = $user->update('last_login', $dateNow);

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Full code:::

The login:

```
if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();
        $cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');
        $dateNow = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
        $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);
        $loginTime = $user->update('last_login', $dateNow);
        }
        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('/admin/index');
            $loginTime;
        }
    }
```

Update class

```
public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }

    if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the implementation of `$this->_db->update`?

Comment: your `update` function get 2 parameters, the first of them must be an array (you defined that). But you call the function passing a string ("last_login") as first parameter.

Comment: @GiacomoM ahh gotcha. Ok, I changed it to `$loginTime = $user->update(array('last_login' => $dateNow));` and it now works. Except the hours number it wrong. It shows the hour at 7, when it should be 15. Is this something I have to change in the code or db?

Comment: the second parameter is the `id`, you are passing `$dateNow`

Comment: Btw you should study OOP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: @GiacomoM The code is working and getting the correct id. How is it not OOP?

Comment: it is OOP, but it seems you miss fundamentals of OOP. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: @GiacomoM What exactly are you referring to though?

Comment: a couple of things: for example I would not pass the id of the user to the `update` function. An `User` instance should be an user record on the database, so probably I would pass the id to the constructor.

Comment: @GiacomoM Thanks for the info!